# Technical details of Android Garbage Collector

Tags: android, multithreading, garbage-collection, android-3.0-honeycomb

As I'm doing a research on commonalities/differences of various mobile platforms, one of the aspects under investigation is memory management. As such, I'm interested in more detailed technical information on the various mechanisms.

In specific, e.g. **which garbage collector type does Android use**?
([[Google Groups Discussion]](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/6ecb8ea2b18fa165/ce60a4781f41b786?lnk=raot&pli=1) suggests that it is using "tracing" mechanism - but I'd appreciate a "more official" source which I could possibly quote, plus hoping to find information there *which implications the type could have on the programmer*).

Also among my questions is **in what way the GC in Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) has been tweaked specifically to utilize multiple processors**?
[Android Devevelopers Guide] suggests that

> Android 3.0 is the first version of the platform designed to run on either single or multicore processor architectures. A variety of changes in the Dalvik VM, Bionic library, and elsewhere add support for symmetric multiprocessing in multicore environments. These optimizations can benefit all applications, even those that are single-threaded. For example, with two active cores, a single-threaded application might still see a performance boost if the Dalvik garbage collector runs on the second core. The system will arrange for this automatically."

As before, I'd rather find a source with more technical information to read upon this. Again, *what's the impact on the developer* (other than the obvious that increased performance could be hoped for)?

Any such input is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

To answer one of your questions, the [Dalvik VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) indeed does use a tracing garbage collector, using a [Mark and Sweep](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page424.html) approach.

According to [The Dalvik Virtual Machine Architecture](http://show.docjava.com/posterous/file/2012/12/10222640-The_Dalvik_Virtual_Machine.pdf):

> The current strategy in the Dalvik garbage collector is to keep mark bits,
>   or the bits that indicate that a particular object is “reachable” and
>   therefore should not be garbage collected, separate from other heap memory.

From Android 5.0 (Lollipop) and on, Dalvik was replaced with the [Android Runtime (ART)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime)).

Google has the following to say about the changes in the garbage collector from Dalvik to ART <sup>([source](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/index.html#Improved_GC))</sup>:

> ### Improved garbage collection
>
> Garbage collection (GC) can impair an app's performance, resulting in
>   choppy display, poor UI responsiveness, and other problems. ART
>   improves garbage collection in several ways:
>
> - One GC pause instead of two
> - Parallelized processing during the remaining GC pause
> - Collector with lower total GC time for the special case of cleaning up recently-allocated, short-lived objects
> - Improved garbage collection ergonomics, making concurrent garbage collections more timely, which makes GC_FOR_ALLOC events extremely
>     rare in typical use cases
>     Compacting GC to reduce background memory usage and fragmentation

See also:

- [The source code of the Dalvik garbage collector](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/android-4.3_r2/vm/alloc/MarkSweep.cpp)
- [The source code of the ART garbage collector](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/master/runtime/gc/)

Comment: I take it from your great links that "The main disadvantage of the mark-and-sweep approach is the fact that that normal program execution is suspended while the garbage collection algorithm runs. In particular, this can be a problem in a program that interacts with a human user or that must satisfy real-time execution constraints. For example, an interactive application that uses mark-and-sweep garbage collection becomes unresponsive periodically."  
Would be interesting to find technical details on how and to what extent Honeycomb's support for multiprocessors can mitigate this disadvantage!?

Comment: So there's no copying involved whatsoever between heap spaces (e.g. from eden space to other spaces?) i.o.w. Android's GC does not use any form of generational/statistical collection strategies?

Comment: Looking at the source code, I see its marking white, black and grey, so it appears to be tri-color marking.

Comment: @mr.icetea: The post has been updated both to fix the Dalvik links, and to include a comment about ART, the current Android runtime.