# Why does Android garbage collect so many times with Jacksons ObjectMapper?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, jackson

My Android app has a custom AsyncTask to make a rest call for a list of objects. I'm using Jackson to convert my response into Java and I am seeing about 30 garbage collections calls when mapping the Json via ObjectMapper.readValue(). Interestingly enough, if I make the same call a second, third, fourth time (by selecting a refresh button), there is only a single GC call. Any ideas why this is happening on the first call every time I start my Android App?

AsyncTask.java

```
doInBackground() {

HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpClientUtil.setJsonAccept(request);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
HttpEntity responseEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity());

// Call that garbage collect 30+ times the first exectution
ArrayList<MyObject> responseCollection = mapper.readValue(responseEntity.getContent(), new TypeReference<ArrayList<MyObject>>(){});

return responseCollection;
}
```

LogCat Output

```
07-10 11:05:13.484: D/dalvikvm(5518): GC_CONCURRENT freed 497K, 5% free 14030K/14727K, paused 3ms+4ms
07-10 11:05:13.484: D/dalvikvm(5518): GC_CONCURRENT freed 497K, 5% free 14030K/14727K, paused 3ms+4ms
07-10 11:05:13.484: D/dalvikvm(5518): GC_CONCURRENT freed 497K, 5% free 14030K/14727K, paused 3ms+4ms
...
```

Comment: The GC on Android is aggressive overall, it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with Jackson. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818869/technical-details-of-android-garbage-collector

Comment: @ChristopherPerry So that seems like the answer, please put it in and close :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GC on Android is aggressive overall, it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with Jackson. More info here:

[Technical details of Android Garbage Collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818869/technical-details-of-android-garbage-collector)